# Reload Angular UI Modal, Without Reloading Rest of Page

Tags: angularjs, three.js, angular-ui

I am loading a 3D object using three.js within an Angular UI Modal. The 3D image loads correctly, however, when I update the texture wrapping the 3D object the update does not display unless I refresh the page. I have tried multiple options in three.js but none are working so I would like to see if I can do the equivalent of a "page refresh" but only on the Modal as I have other elements on the page I don't want refreshed.

The Modal is opened onclick via a button named "Open Modal". It opens this HTML code that is then populated with the 3D object via the controller:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Box Preview</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" data-ng-controller="appBoxDisplayCtrl">

    <div id="webGL-container" width="100%">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Close</button>
</div>
```

I have a controller dedicated to what I load into the Modal as follows:

```
appControllers.controller('appBoxDisplayCtrl', ['$scope', 'appBoxPreview', function ($scope, appBoxPreview) {

// 3D OBJECT - Variables
var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;
var box;
var controls;
var newtexture;

// 3D OBJECT - Generate

$scope.generate3D = function () {
newtexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("https://myblobservice.net/Texture_0.png");

//Instantiate a Collada loader
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load('https://myblobservice.net/dae.dae', function (collada) {

box = collada.scene;

box.traverse(function (child) {

if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
                        animation.play();
}
});

box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
box.updateMatrix();

init();
animate();
});

function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);

renderer.setSize(500, 500);

// Load the box file
scene.add(box);

// Lighting
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight();
scene.add(light);

// Camera
camera.position.x = 40;
camera.position.y = 40;
camera.position.z = 40;

camera.lookAt(scene.position);

// Rotation Controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 5;

controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;

$("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
}

// Initial 3D Load
$scope.generate3D();

}]);
```

I also have a controller for managing the Modal instance dependency:

```
appControllers.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Any chance you could setup a plunk or fiddle to recreate the issue?

Comment: I can't because the box object and images I can't post externally

Comment: Is there a method in three.js to redraw the image?

Comment: Good thinking. My code above should rerender it from what I understand, but I am newer to three.js so I'm not sure. It appears that the texture is getting cached

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);` This moves the scope outside of angular meaning if the `renderer` updates it would not refresh.

You will want to `$watch` the value that is changing then use **three.js** to refresh the image.

Technically because you are manipulating the `DOM` you should put rendering using `three.js` into a `directive`.

Comment: Would a $scope.$apply work as well, or are you thinking I would watch the newtexture variable for a change? Can watch detect a change on that?

Comment: It seems like you would be coming from `$scope` to outside.  `$scope.$apply` would be for getting something from jQuery and updating the scope.

Comment: I am little lost on how to setup the $watch for my code, given that newtexture is what will be updated. Can you provide an additional push on how to set this up?

Comment: It may not be looking like something watch can manage. As an example, if I use the Angular method of appending, I get the same issues:  var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#webGL-container'));
                myEl.append(renderer.domElement);